# c# - Programmatically remove attachments from outlook email

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to remove all attachments form a mail in outlook. Don't know, what I'm doing wrong. The code does not cause an exception, but the attachments are still available after removing. This is my code:

This gives me an outlook.application object if it is running or is running outlook, if it's not running:

```
    public static OL.Application GetOutlook(out bool StillRunning)
    {
        OL.Application OLApp = null;

        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count() > 0)
        {
            StillRunning = true;
            return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;
        }
        else
        {
            StillRunning = false;
            OLApp = new OL.Application();
            OL.NameSpace nameSpace = OLApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nameSpace.Logon("", "", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            nameSpace = null;
            return OLApp;
        }
    }
```

This function returns a mail by its EntryID:

```
public static OL.MailItem GetMailByEntryId(OL.Application OlApp, string MailItemEntryID)
    {
        OL.NameSpace olNS = null;
        object obj = null;
        olNS = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        if (olNS == null) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Unable to get Namespace 'MAPI' in Outlook.Application object!"); }

        OL.MailItem MI = null;
        obj = olNS.GetItemFromID(MailItemEntryID);
        if (obj != null && obj is OL.MailItem) { MI = obj as OL.MailItem; }
        if (MI == null) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Unable to get mail item by ID " + System.Environment.NewLine + MailItemEntryID); }

        return MI;
    }
```

Here, I try to remove the attachments of the mail:

```
    public static void RemoveAttachments(string EntryID)
    {
        bool StillRunning = false;
        OL.Application OLApp = GetOutlook(out StillRunning);

        OL.MailItem MI = GetMailByEntryId(OLApp, EntryID);

        for(int i = 0; i < MI.Attachments.Count; i++) { MI.Attachments.Remove(i); } //Methode Delete() not available...

        MI.Save();

        if (!StillRunning) { OLApp.Quit(); OLApp = null; System.GC.Collect(); KillOutlook(); }
    }
```

Thank you all for your help...

Comment: You havent shown how you itterate the mail items, where is entryID coming from, why not just pass the mail item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All collections in OOM (including `MailItem.Attachments`) are 1 based, not 0. You are also modifying the collection while looping - use a down loop:

```
Attachments attachments = MI.Attachments;
for(int i = attachments.Count; i >= 1; i--) { Attachments.Remove(i); }
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you very much - now I know, why it's not deleting all files.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, got it - You can make it work that way:

```
foreach(OL.Attachment Att in MI.Attachments){Att.Delete();}
```